# Delete thumbnail by id

Tags: android, thumbnails

I use below code to get photo's path and id:

```
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA};  
Cursor cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID); 
int count = cursor.getCount();
int image_column_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID); 
int image_path_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
int i;
for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
cursor.moveToPosition(i);
long id = cursor.getInt(image_column_index);
String p = cursor.getString(image_path_index);
photo.add(id, p);
}
```

And use below code to get thumbnail:

```
bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
```

While I delete one photo by its path.
The thumbnail of the delete one's still exist.
How to delete the thumbnail at the same time?

Comment: What is `photo`? Can't you use the `id` you get in that for loop to query the `MediatStore.Images.Thumbnails` provider and delete the thumbnail?

Comment: photo is LinkedList<long, String>.

Comment: I don't know how to get the thumbnail position by id or delete it by id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `id` from the query for the images(the `MediaStore.Images.Media._ID` column) and then query the `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` to delete the thumbnail with the `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID` equal to that id(`IMAGE_ID` is the same id as the id from `MediaStore.Images.Media._ID`).

```
long id = cursor.getInt(image_column_index); // this is the id from MediaStore.Images.Media._ID but also the IMAGE_ID from MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails

// if you delete the photo with this above id and also want to delete the thumbnail:
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver(); // in an Activity
cr.delete(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + " = ?", new String[] {"" + id});
```

I didn't play much with the `MediaStore` so this could be wrong.